# Finding the nullspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

I am still struggling to understand the relationship between the row echelon form and the basis of the nullspace.  I have a questions that asks me to find the diagonalized normal form of a matrix A.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & b & 1\\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial works out to be $P_{A}(\lambda)=\lambda^2(b-\lambda)$.  Giving eigenvalues $\lambda=0$ with algebraic multiplicity 2 and $\lambda_{2}=2$ with algebraic multiplicity 1.

If I do gaussian elimination to get row reduced echelon form by swapping R1 with R3 then deviding R2 by b to get the pivot set up I get....

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 1 & 1/b\\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

So does this mean $x_3=x_3$ being a free variable, then from there I am a bit confused.

Comment: Yes, $x_3$ is free  - can you write down the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ for the nullspace? The set of such vectors is your nullspace. I don't know how this relates to your preamble about eigenvalues.

Comment: x1=0, and then x2=x3/b?

Comment: This will end up requiring jordan normla form and finding generalized eigenspaces.

Comment: $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = -\frac{x_3}{b}$ so that the nullspace of A is all multiples of the basis vector  $(0,  -\frac{1}{b}, 1)$, a line of points through the origin.

Comment: Thanks paul I actually ended up solving this.  Nice to see I was on the right track.